# How can I manipulate key value of a dictionary

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the following dict in ansible:

```
finder_expand_infopane: 
  - { name: General , value: yes }
  - { name: MetaData , value: yes }
  - { name: OpenWith , value: yes }
  - { name: Comments , value: no }
  - { name: Preview , value: no }
  - { name: Privileges , value: yes }
```

How can I use set_fact to create a second dict where the value key gets modified with the following filters?
`| bool | string() | lower`

So the dict I need should look like this:

```
finder_expand_infopane_parsed: 
  - { name: General , value: true }
  - { name: MetaData , value: true }
  - { name: OpenWith , value: true }
  - { name: Comments , value: false }
  - { name: Preview , value: false }
  - { name: Privileges , value: true }
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What's the difference between the two dicts? Boolean values are Boolean values. It doesn't matter how they are represented.

Comment: I need that for a when statement like this `when: finder_expand_fileinfo_status.results[item.0].stdout != item.1.value` the content of stdout is a lowercase bool, if I want to compare that i also need a lowercase bool, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate required elements as temporary facts and then extract them as a single list from registered variable.

Here's an example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    finder_expand_infopane:
      - { name: General , value: yes }
      - { name: MetaData , value: yes }
      - { name: OpenWith , value: yes }
      - { name: Comments , value: no }
      - { name: Preview , value: no }
      - { name: Privileges , value: yes }
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        tmp_item:
          name: "{{ item.name }}"
          value: "{{ item.value | bool | string() | lower }}"
      register: tmp_items
      with_items: "{{ finder_expand_infopane }}"
    - set_fact:
        res: "{{ tmp_items.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.tmp_item') | list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ res }}"
```

In a more general way you can generate only additional values and merge original items with additional generated properties. See [this post](https://ansibledaily.com/process-complex-variables-with-set_fact-and-with_items/) for details.